# IllegalStateException - Could not load 'DispatcherServlet.properties' issue

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, websphere

I am trying to deploy `Spring MVC` application on `Websphere` using `RSA 7.5`.

1. I created a new profile and adjusted all profile setting.
2. I created a new server to work with the new profile.
3. I configured the workspace class path with all the needed jars.

But while publishing/starting the application on the server I always found the below exception.

```
[20/05/15 15:15:48:710 AST] 00000016 WebExtensionP E   Error occured while       preparing the servlet for initialization. 
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1399)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:388)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1243)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:152)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:882)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:804)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:522)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:359)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:292)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:92)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:157)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:666)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:619)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1138)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:569)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:817)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:949)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2122)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:216)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1328)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:219)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:63)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1334)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1329)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load 'DispatcherServlet.properties': class path resource [DispatcherServlet.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:267)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:194)
... 30 more
```

I can't understand why he couldn't load `DispatcherServlet.properties` while it already exists at `spring-webmvc.jar` in my `webinf/lib`

Comment: What can you do to reduce the variables to the problem? Can you try deploying the Spring app on another stack instead of Websphere? Can you deploy a new Spring project with almost nothing in it to Websphere? Can you move your `DispatcherServlet.properties` file outside the jar and access it from a different location?

Comment: I don't access **DispatcherServlet.properties** , this file accessed by Spring DispatcherServlet.java. That is why when spring try to load this class it throw this exception.

Comment: ok. My first question is really the important part; all the other ones are just suggestions to try to simplify the problem. Can you make the simplest possible set-up/program in which your problem happens?

Comment: no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), so please leave out thanks and any help bla bla